# [CLOCK TIMED ACTION]

Tags: excel, vba, function, time, clock

Looking for a code to activate a function that i made called "IV" at 9:00 pm every day.

i tried following some other scripts but i can get it to activate the function using clock time.

Comment: Does the trigger have to be in VBA? You could trigger this by opening your workbook using autohotkey and writing a procedure in the on open event to call your procedure then close the workbook again? Otherwise the workbook has to be open all the time and running a macro.

Comment: that makes total sense, but how would i get it to trigger my macro in the code ? sorry if im asking to much but if you have any key words to search i would appreciate anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using windows.

You could use a sleep function to control the process, but when you run macros you can't access your sheets in excel. VBA is not really set up for this type of thing so I propose another method.

Open up visual basic and put this in Thisworkbook:

```
Private Sub Woorbook_Open()
    yourmacro.IV() 
    ThisWorkbook.Close()
End Sub
```

Where you just substitute the names of `yourmacro` with the name of the macro file which contains your prodedure called `IV`.

This will run when the workbook is opened by the task scheduler, run the procedure, then close the workbook.

Then make a new task using windows task scheduler that opens this workbook at 9pm every night. (tutorial here: https://datacornering.com/how-to-run-excel-file-from-windows-10-task-scheduler/)

Comment: wow this is awsome what you just sent! i just need a code to trigger the macro at a time once the book is open.

Comment: I took this code from this tutorial here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-a-macro-automatically-when-workbook-opens-in-excel/. Will update the answer with more information.

Comment: This code does that.